# Question about the solution to the SDE $dX_t = 1_{(0,\infty)}(X_t)dB_t, \; X_0 \coprod B$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to understand the following example from René Schilling's Brownian Motion.

Here, we try to solve the one-dimensional SDE
$$dX_t = 1_{(0,\infty)}(X_t)dB_t, \; X_0 = x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Take the stopping time $\tau = \inf \{t \ge 0: x+B_t \le 0\}$, and set $X_t:= x+B_{t\wedge \tau}$.

Then, it is clear from the equations here, since $\tau(\omega)>s$ is the same as $x+B_{s\wedge\tau(\omega)}(\omega)>0$ (by the continuity of the Brownian Motion), and we get the result.

But why does this argument still hold if the initial condition $X_0$ is a random variable independent of $B_t$? In this case, I think we need to take the product space of $X_0$ and $B_t$, but I am not sure how to formulate the equivalence of the middle equality.

I have been struggling to set these details out. I would greatly appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For $s<\tau$ you have $x+B_s>0$ and for $s\ge \tau $ you get $x+B_{s\land\tau}=x+B_\tau=0$ so that indeed the claimed equality holds.

If $X_0$ is a random variable, it has of course also to be used in the construction of the random variable $\tau$. The whole computation only invokes one single point of the probability space, if you fix that point then it is simple calculus (with Ito integrals).

Comment: What do you mean the computation only invokes a single point of the probability space? And where does the independence comes to play in the computation? Can you show the explicit computations here? Because I am not familiar with this kind of setting.

Comment: You are not computing any expectations, so the whole computation is in time direction only, "orthogonal" to the probability space $\Omega$. That's why it has no influence if $X_0$ is a constant or a random variable, as for a fixed $\omega\in\Omega$, $X_0(\omega)$ is a constant.

Comment: Oh I see the point. But then why is it necessary that $X_0$ is independent of $B$?

Comment: For $t\mapsto X_t$ to be adapted to the filtration, you need that $X_0$ is a random variable relative to $\cal F_0$. This forcibly makes it independent of $B$. The reverse is IMO not necessarily true, it would only follow naturally if the filtration is generated only by $B$. (But that opinion might be wrong, as $\cal F_0$ can not be the trivial $\sigma$-algebra in this context.)

Comment: Sorry but please could you enlighten me a bit more as I don't follow. Why does $X_0 \in \mathscr{F}_0$ force $X_0$ to be independent of $B$? And why does the reverse follow naturally if the filtration is generated only by $B$?